# Laravel belongsToMany select all specified ids

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, eloquent-relationship

Relation

```
    public function groups()
    {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ItemGroup','item_to_group','item_id','item_group_id');
    }
```

**
How to select all Items that have item_group_id 0 and 9 BOTH?**

```
    $zero_and_nine_count = \App\Models\Item::with(['groups' => function ($query) {
        $where[] = ['item_group_id', , 0];
        $where[] = ['item_group_id', '=', 9];
        $query->where($where);
    }])->count();
```

Counts all Items

Working SQL:

```
SELECT item_id FROM `item_to_group` WHERE `item_group_id` = 9 AND item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM `item_to_group` WHERE `item_group_id` = 0)
```

Comment: [Subquery](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#subquery-where-clauses) Laravel now does have Subquery support so do look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference :

```sql
SELECT item_id 
FROM `item_to_group` 
WHERE 
    `item_group_id` = 9 AND 
    item_id IN (
        SELECT item_id 
        FROM `item_to_group` 
        WHERE `item_group_id` = 0
    )
```

You can query like this  :

```php
$items = \App\Models\Item::whereHas('groups', function ($query) {
        $query->where('item_group_id', 9)
            ->whereIn('item_id', function ($subquery) {
                $subquery->select('item_id')
                    ->from('item_to_group')
                    ->where('item_group_id', 0);
            });
    })->get();
```

Comment: Thx a lot, this solution i had, but i thought that laravel is so smart that there will be more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)?

```
$model->groups()->whereIn('item_group_id', [0, 9])->get();
```

Comment: no, OP is looking for subquery in the eloquent format

Comment: whereIn is OR logic, i need AND logic